# Namespace entries in PSR-1 standard?

Tags: php, namespaces, standards, psr-1

I am looking for the correct way (if either is correct please let me know) to write namespaces in PHP classes that follow PSR-1 standard. I looked around but didn't see anything specific. Is the correct way to use

```
Namespace Foo\Bar;
```

or is it correct to use curly braces such as

```
Namespace Foo\Bar
{
    // ....
}
```

If both are correct, is there a particular reason to use one over the other? I realize that this portion might be opinion based though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bracketed namespace is the [recommended method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php) for defining multiple namespaces in a single file.

If you only have one namespace in a file then use the non-bracketed version.

PSR-1 recommends one class per file, so you should probably limit yourself to one namespace per file, too.

Answer (score 3):

Form [Namespace and Class Names PSR-1 standrad](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md#3-namespace-and-class-names):

> Namespaces and classes MUST follow an "autoloading" PSR: [[PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), [PSR-4]](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md).
>
> This means **each class is in a file by itself**, and is in a namespace of at least one level: a top-level vendor name.
>
> Code written for PHP 5.3 and after MUST use formal namespaces :

Example :

```
namespace Vendor\Model;

class Foo
{
}
```

This means that PSR-1 standard recommends the use of your first form, because with the second one (which uses curly braces) you could have more than one namespace in a single file, and this way you're not following the PSR-1 standard for namespaces.